# Bind sails.js app to a specific ip

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js

I have a Nodejs project and is using sails.js mvc framework. Now, Im ready to deploy it, but before that one requirement is to bind it to a different ip. Is there a way on sails.js that we can achieve this? What file or config should I update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change the 'host' key. [Source](https://coderwall.com/p/dhhfcw)

You can change the `/config/local.js` file and add the 'host' key to it :

```
{
    port: '1234',
    host: '111.111.111.111',
    environment: 'production'
}
```

[Source](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/anatomy/myApp/config/local.js.html)

Comment: Putting this in **config/local.js** is fine and will always take precedence over your other config files.  The potential drawback is that it is not (by default) version-controlled (it is ignored by Git).  An alternative to solution is to put this in a separate, version-controlled file (Shen Lance's solution), which you can override with **local.js**.  An even better solution in v0.10.x is to use the environment-specific config files (**config/env/development.js**, **config/env/production.js**) to manage the host for different environments.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried @xShirase answer and it worked too. So I have it marked as answer. Anyhow, this is what I did on my end:

I added `application.js` on config, `config/application.js` then added this line `module.exports.host = '<ip here>';`