# Accessing Dokku App url

Tags: amazon-ec2, sails.js, dokku

I have deployed a sails application with dokku on a amazon ec2 instance. After deployment I ran`dokku run  app-name sails console` and my sails app is running when I check the sails logs its says its running on localhost:5000.
And `dokku app-name url` will give me a url `example.com` but when I try to access example.com in the browser it doesn't work. Isn't the app supposed to run on that url given by dokku?  and when I hit that url shouldn't the ngnix proxy to localhost:5000 ?

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

Your application should be listening on the `0.0.0.0` interface, as otherwise the nginx process outside of the container cannot proxy to it.

Comment: How do I make sure/configure that its listening on `0.0.0.0` interface ?

Comment: Thats something that you'll need to figure out for sails. Looks like you can set the `host` config option to that interface: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26208664/bind-sails-js-app-to-a-specific-ip